# Upgrading manjaro system fails when install lib32-libcanberra

Tags: upgrade, manjaro

I used `pacman -Syu` to upgrade my Manjaro system, but some new libraries like `lib32-libcanberra-pulse` and `libcanberra-pulse` failed to be installed due to the dependencies.

I have tried twice whether the libraries are to be replaced or not, but both attempts fail. Details are shown below.

How can I install these libraries and continue to upgrade the system?

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace lib32-libcanberra-pulse with multilib/lib32-libcanberra? [Y/n] Y
:: Replace libcanberra-pulse with extra/libcanberra? [Y/n] Y
:: Replace qca with extra/qca-qt5? [Y/n] Y
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing lib32-libcanberra (0.30+2+gc0620e4-4) breaks dependency 'lib32-libcanberra=0.30+2+gc0620e4-3' required by lib32-libcanberra-gstreamer
:: installing libcanberra (0.30+2+gc0620e4-4) breaks dependency 'libcanberra=0.30+2+gc0620e4-3' required by libcanberra-gstreamer

$ sudo pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace lib32-libcanberra-pulse with multilib/lib32-libcanberra? [Y/n] n
:: Replace libcanberra-pulse with extra/libcanberra? [Y/n] n
:: Replace qca with extra/qca-qt5? [Y/n] n
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing lib32-libcanberra (0.30+2+gc0620e4-4) breaks dependency 'lib32-libcanberra=0.30+2+gc0620e4-3' required by lib32-libcanberra-gstreamer
:: installing lib32-libcanberra (0.30+2+gc0620e4-4) breaks dependency 'lib32-libcanberra=0.30+2+gc0620e4-3' required by lib32-libcanberra-pulse
:: installing libcanberra (0.30+2+gc0620e4-4) breaks dependency 'libcanberra=0.30+2+gc0620e4-3' required by libcanberra-gstreamer
:: installing libcanberra (0.30+2+gc0620e4-4) breaks dependency 'libcanberra=0.30+2+gc0620e4-3' required by libcanberra-pulse
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to read the [announcements](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/stable-update-2021-06-14-kernels-browsers-mesa-deepin-systemd-gnome-apps-40-2-pipewire-haskell/70192/2)

> You might be blocked updating when using pacman due to some
> libcanberra packages. Simply remove those packages: sudo pacman -Rdd
> lib32-libcanberra-pulse lib32-libcanberra-gstreamer libcanberra-pulse
> libcanberra-gstreamer. We recommend to use pamac anyway, which does
> this automatically: pamac update

Comment: Sorry I haven't kept an eye on the announcements. Anyway, thank you for your advice and I will pay attentions from now on.

Comment: I sound pedantic sorry but lately things have improved a lot. And whenever you hit a corner like this take a look on the main page.

Comment: Still, valid point to raise the question here, since for me a quick Google search found this answer directly, which was quicker and easier than browsing the official forum.